# attaching divs inside li gives null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to attach classADiv(which has div within divs) to `li` and it's attribute is `squareId`. But I'm getting `classADiv.parentNode` as `null`. how can I check what is the parent of the div and attach it to the 'li`?

```
function attachDivToLi(){

  var square = document.getElementById('squareId');
  var round = document.getElementById('roundId')


  var appleDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var grapesDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var classBDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var classADiv = document.createElement('div');



  classBDiv.appendChild(appleDiv)
  classBDiv.appendChild(grapesDiv)
  classADiv.appendChild(classBDiv)

  if(classADiv.parentNode === square){
    ulDiv.appendChild(classADiv);
    document.body.appendChild(ulDiv);
  }

}
```

Comment: `classADiv` is orphan!  you just created the element but never appended it to a parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Elements that have been created but not added to the DOM yet by definition don't have any parent nodes (unless they're attached to some other newly created element). So you can't test classADiv's parent node before classADiv's been added to the document - that doesn't really make sense.